# Flutter: can't find class "FlutterFragment"

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have a Flutter app create by `flutter create` command.

I have the MainActivity (which extends from `FlutterActivity`) and also a native activity that I opens it via `MethodChannel`.

Now I need to call another `FlutterActivity` embedded with a `FlutterFragment` but the class `FlutterFragment` simply doesn't exists.

My page stack would be like that:

- MainActivity(`FlutterActivity`) -> NativeActivity (with native code and layout) -> AnotherFlutterActivity.

I am following this tutorial: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps

Ayone know why this is happening?

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 10.0.17763.379], locale pt-BR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.30.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you haven't imported `FlutterFragment` in your activity, please add this line in your `import` statements.

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragment;
```

Also, make sure to extend your activity from `FlutterFragmentActivity`. You will have to import it, add this line at the top of your file along with the other `import` statements.

Like so:

```
...
import io.flutter.app.FlutterFragmentActivity;
...
```

***Hope this helps :)***